Prettier on WebStorm triggers multiple compilations
I'm developing (an Angular application) using WebStorm.
I like using Prettier and I have set it up to automatically trigger on save.
This seems to apply Prettier after the file has been saved, which results in two file updates, which triggers two Angular recompilations.
The behavior is pretty consistent and kills compilation time.
I would like to have WebStorm call the format action before saving the file to disk, which I can accomplish calling manually the action Reformat with Prettier followed by a Save.
Can I configure WebStorm to run Prettier before the save?

Not that I'm aware of. This seems like a bug, or at the very least a reasonable request to ask Jetbrains to implement (Before/After save actions).
An alternative solution for you could be to enable the "Reformat code" checkbox when committing your code. It won't prettify while you work, but could save you plenty of time.

The issue you encounter looks similar to this request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48082. Please vote for it to raise its priority.
For now, the only workaround would be to use Prettier via Code | Reformat Code, or via Reformat with Prettier actions as you mentioned.
